# Rich text format area size in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: cms

I've set a schema field to height 2 and see the following for the input area in Chrome and IE.

[image: img]

I'm expecting to have text area that's 2 lines high based on the default text size. I removed the source view option, thinking the tab might affect the size, but it still appears to be about 5 lines in height instead of 2.

It seems to match 2 lines if the text is set to a large font or to a heading. I'd like to minimize the size these fields take in the content entry form as well as hint that authors should enter a smaller amount of text.

**How do I make this match the expected 2 lines?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also see 5 lines, and the smallest I can re-size the field to is 3 lines. I think you will need to file an enhancement request with SDL Customer Support to get the functionality you desire.

Comment: It looks like it. I'll accept we can't change this in the UI and follow up with SDL.

Comment: just out of interest... was this ever followed up with SDL? It's quite an interesting request and I can see the editorial reasoning...